# Converting mysql code to PDO gives no output

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to convert the code given [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/asynchronous-comments-with-jquery-and-json/) to PDO using OOP approach. This is what I've got so far:

comments.PHP:

```
public function loadComments() {
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM `comments`
                      WHERE
                      `comments`.`ImageID`  = :imageid ;";

            try
            {
                $imageid = $_REQUEST['imageid'];



                $query = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
                $params = array(':imageid' => $imageid);
                $query->execute($params); 

                for ($x = 0, $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $x < $row; $x++) {
                 $comments[$x] = array("name" => $row["name"], "comment" => $row["comment"], "date" => $row["date"]);       
                    }

                $response = $_GET["jsoncallback"] . "(" . json_encode($comments) . ")";
                echo $response;
                return TRUE;

            }
            catch(Exception $ex)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
    }
```

Firebug throws the `undefined variable: comments` error.

This is the original code:

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT
                          * FROM `comments`
                          WHERE
                          `comments`.`ImageID`  = '$imageid' ;");

        //loop through and return results
      for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

            $comments[$x] = array("name" => $row["name"], "comment" => $row["comment"], "date" => $row["date"]);            
        }

        //echo JSON to page
        $response = $_GET["jsoncallback"] . "(" . json_encode($comments) . ")";
        echo $response;
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$x < $row` when I think you intend to use `$x < $numrows`

```
for ($x = 0, $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $x < $row; $x++)
                                                          ^^^^^
$numrows = $query->rowCount();
for ($x = 0, $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $x < $numrows; $x++)
```

This whole loop could be better written this way:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $comments[] = array("name" => $row["name"], "comment" => $row["comment"], "date" => $row["date"]);       
}
```

There's no need for the `$x` counter if you use the `$comments[]` syntax, since that will append each new row with a numeric key onto the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is wrong.  You need to get the number of rows, then call `$query->fetch()` on every loop iteration:

```
$numrows = //...
for ($x = 0; $x < $numrows; $x++) {
  $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $comments[$x] = array("name" => $row["name"], "comment" => $row["comment"], "date" => $row["date"]);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line has a syntax error (comma instead of semicolon):

```
for ($x = 0, $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $x < $row; $x++) {
```

It should be:

```
for ($x = 0; $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $x < $row; $x++) {
```

Comment: That comma syntax is actually valid. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php